# Having videos autoplay in modal window

Tags: html5-video, simplemodal, autoplay

I am using a modal window to display multiple videos, but my autoplay seems to be ignored in the modal window. If I have the video on the page and it is not hidden the autoplay is fine. Do I need to do something else to trigger the autoplay in a modal window?

I am using [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) to do the modal window. For the video I am using a simple video tag and an mp4 video with the autoplay boolean on.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I was only able to get this to work by using a javascript play() call in the 'open' handler for a jQuery UI dialog.  No other method would work.. maybe simplemodal has an analog?  Here is the solution for jQuery UI:

```
$('div#mydialog').dialog({
    open: function(event, ui)   {
        $('video#myvideo').get(0).play();   
    }
});
```